How to create partition for QNX6fs?
I want to run RPI with QNX 7.1. I can boot RPI with 1 partition of type FAT32. It has QNX kernel and necessary configuration files. But I want to have 2nd partition of type qnx6fs for to mount root filesystem in it.
How to create qnx6fs on SD card?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04. It has kernel module qnx4 but not qnx6.
